# Frame with dent

Tags: frames, safety, damage

I recently bought a bike and then realized it had a dent on the top tube. I would like to know your opinion if it is safe to ride. The bike is a Devinci Cameleon made from double butted aluminium. The purpose of the bike is only to go to work. No downhills.

The paint was affected because of the impact, but is not flaking and the tube is straight.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the tube is still straight, and there are not any visible cracks (other than perhaps flaking of the paint) then it should be OK.  You do want to keep an eye on it, though, watching for the development of cracks in that area.

Comment: I assume you bought the bike used? If it's new, take it back to the shop for replacement.

Comment: That middle picture is worrisome, since it looks like you can see the crack in the metal.  Hard to say without being there, though.

Answer (score 2):

Add this area to your monthly bike maint/check routine.

That is, look at it every month, perhaps take a photo and decide if its growing or not.  If not, is fine.  If the dent starts flexing, paint starts flaking, or anything like a crack appears then stop riding it and reassess.

And if the handling changes, stop immediately and check the whole bike over - even in the middle of a ride.